# Backbone model doesn't have getters when used defaults function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having two models in Backbone

```
var CustomModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: function() {
        return { 
            customRecord: {
            fields:         {},
           }
        }
    }
```

and

```
var SubModel = CustomModel.extend({

        defaults: function() {
             return _.extend( _.result(CustomModel.prototype,'defaults'), 
            {
                id  : null
           })}
```

Now If I create a subModel like

```
var model = new SubModel();
```

The model has all the attributes - `customRecord` and `id`. But I don't find getters for the attributes in the subclass. For example, If I call, `model.getId()` (id being a member attribute of subModel), it throws an error saying `undefined function`.

I can use only functions in the super class and not the subclass. If I don't use default function, instead use default as an object, then all works fine. But when I change to using defaults function, my sub class methods are not available.

Any one can help?

Comment: `var SubModel : CustomModel.extend({` or `var SubModel = CustomModel.extend({`? And where do you expect this `getId()` function to com from? What is `CustomHC1Model`? Perhaps a complete (but minimal) example would help.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Corrected the typo.

Comment: You should get an attribute value using the model.get('attr') function. The one you're trying to use is undefined because is actually inexistent in the backbone base object.

Comment: So what is `getId`? Where does that come from?

Comment: Commented, to short for an answer: Backbone does not generate getter functions like `getFoo()` for you. The Backbone way is [to call `get("foo")`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get).

Comment: Note, that your `defaults()` implementation whould be more readable if using `_.omit(_.result(CustomModel.prototype,'defaults'), "id")`. [Underscore on omit()`](http://underscorejs.org/#omit)